# Exception : "The operation cannot be performed because the message has been changed."

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I have code:

```
public void ExportEmail(Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonControl control)
{
   MailItem mailItem = this.extractor.ExtractMailItem(control);
   mailItem.MessageClass = "Bla bla";
   mailItem.Save();//Exception after second call
   //edit code////
   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailItem);
   mailItem = null;
   ///////////////
   this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<ExportEmailEvent>().Publish(mailItem);
}
```

When I first time press button this code works fine. But second time I get exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException{"The operation cannot be
>   performed because the message has been changed."}

Exception is on `mailItem.Save();`.

Comment: From what I have read, this could be due to a draft of the message being saved.  Have you checked that?

Comment: What kind of message store is this? PST or Exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd suggest releasing underlying COM objects ionstantly. Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. You can read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945(v=office.12).aspx) article.

Is the message class changed after your first call? Did you try to debug the code? Is there any difference? Is it a new message (not-saved yet)?

Comment: I edited code. I added ReleaseComObject but it is same. On debug I don't see any difference.

Comment: But after break, if I call function third time, than MessageClass is set.

Comment: i was also getting this exception but its very strange  after exception if read some property and then save it works LOL i thought mail changes so read some propetry so it is marked unchanged again... haaahaa
try{mail.Save();}catch(Exception ex){ string subject=mail.Subject; mail.Save();}